# Groovy referencing variable without declaration

Tags: eclipse, groovy

Why doesn't eclipse show an error when I use a variable without declaring it?

[image]

**Edit:**

AFAIK dynamic nature only means that type of variable is not known until run time. The variables must still be defined (explicitly or implicitly) before being used. For example - Python which is also a dynamic language reports this as an error.

[image]

**Edit2:**
How does groovy interpret this code so that it still isn't an error?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in dynamic languages like groovy, one could have implemented `methodMissing()` / `propertyMissing()`. So although such variable or method does not actually exist, it may be still not be an errors until the program is actually run. Such errors can usually only be detected at runtime and hence IDE's usually don't complain about it.

Although to hint you, eclipse is underlining such variables there which it is not able to statically reference.

EDIT :

To explain the concept by code example, just check the method test below. Now IDE can't know that `something` , `that` ... can actually be a method in this class.

This vastly helps in building DSLs in groovy.

```
class TestClass {
    def test() {
        def a = something.that.didnt.exist()
        or how about some random statements that make no sense at all
        a = ew Parser().doSomething() ew blah blah blah 
    }
     def propertyMissing(String name) { println "$name"; return this }
     def methodMissing(String name, args) { println "$name with $args"; return this  }
}

new TestClass().test()
```

Comment: @KshitizSharma  Yes, a local variable can be added (via the metaClass) or via propertyMissing as kunal says

Comment: @KshitizSharma I have added an code example to explain the point.

Comment: @kunal That clarifies things and I would ask about Python in another question. But could you explain the third screen shot?

Comment: @KshitizSharma I have done the code changes to respond to third screenshot verbatim. Can you please try putting the code in editor and run it. This is a working code. That will explain you why editor did not have right to complain.

Comment: @kunal I have run it but I do not understand how that explains the third screenshot. `ew ew blah blah` are 4 missing properties. But how do 4 variables with no operators between them make sense?

Comment: As you see in the example above, it can actually run although you never declared all those methods/properties that are used in the method `test()`. But that does not mean the code had error. Code works perfectly fine. So why would an IDE complain for this. Methods can come to class by lot of runtime magic. This was just one example. Another such is metaClass as @tim_yates mentioned. So IDE can not tell just by looking at your class that a method/field that it can not found will not be found when the program runs.

Comment: @KshitizSharma The groovy parser will convert `a b c d` to `a( b ).c( d )`, ie: 2 method calls and 2 properties.  This came in Groovy 1.8.  See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+1.8+release+notes#Groovy18releasenotes-CommandchainsfornicerDomain-SpecificLanguages

Answer (score 2):

I think you may try to use @CompileStatic tag on method.
Then Eclipse will compile and check errors at compile time or in develop time.

I haven't Eclipse to check this now, so this is just for a proposal.